# Problema con cors

Tags: ionic, express

Quiero hacer una app con `ionic` y `expressjs`, pero obtengo este error:

Este es el git del proyecto: https://github.com/hubmanS/GameStix

para levantar el backend con `nodemon server` y el frontend con `ionic server`

Esto tengo en el `app.js` de `expressjs`.

```
var app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());


var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
}


app.use(allowCrossDomain);
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

y desde `ionic` quiero llamar al `backend`.

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        super(http);
        this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/customers/`);    
         console.log('MENSAJE', this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/customers`));
    }
```

Supuestamente debe entrar a este `router`.

```
router.get('/customers', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('NOMAS');
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

pero no se ejecuta el `console`.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar en `NodeJS` el **CORS** de permitir todas las peticiones a la peticion en concreto de tu servidor que carga **IONIC**

Comment: @josanangel puse http://localhost:8100 el cual es el concreto.

Comment: @josanangel estoy queriendo crear una app para celular, es posible crear con ionic + expressjs?

Comment: no lo se a ciencia cierta pero `IONIC` es un **framework** de **ANGULAR** por tanto yo diria que si

Comment: prueba esto en el `CORS` , cambia lo que tienes de `*` por esto `app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://yourapp.com'
}));` donde el `origin` es tu direccion del `frontend` , en tu caso el servidor que corre tu app en `IONIC`

Comment: @josanangel sigo obteniendo el mismo error

Comment: Estoy viendo que tu backend no esta escuchando ningun `puerto` , prueba a   implementar la funcion `app.listen()` tu aplicacion no veo que este escuchando ningun puerto, por tanto no tiene ningun canal de comunicacion

Comment: @josanangel app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
}); pongo esto abajo y me sale puerto en uso

Comment: pon el puerto 5000

Comment: @josanangel sigue saliendo el mismo error de cors.

Comment: pero has cambiado la del puerto de la peticion `http` desde **IONIC** tambien??

Comment: @josanangel Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:5000/customers' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.   si me muestra el mismo mensaje

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92483/discussion-between-josanangel-and-hubman).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema está tanto en el lado Cliente como en lado Servidor.

## **SERVIDOR**

Una de las recomendaciones que puedo hacer en cuanto al uso de [Express](http://expressjs.com/) es que tomes siempre en cuenta el orden en que usas las funciones *middleware* que pasas a tu servidor.

En tu código veo que has intentado por muchos medios solventar el problema de [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

El paquete [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) de NPM, pretende solucionar muchos de los problemas que se presentan a la hora de utilizar dominios cruzados en nuestras aplicaciones.

Luego, intentas usar el método `header()` de Express. Dicho método es un alias de [`set()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set), que a su vez es un método propio del framework (Express).

En Node disponemos de [`setHeader()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) que realiza la misma tarea que `set()`.

Ahora, ¿cuál es la diferencia? Ambos realizan la misma tarea: establecen o escriben un `Header` en el objeto `Response`. Pero, `setHeader()` permite establecer únicamente un par *clave-valor* cada vez que es llamado, mientras que `set()` nos permite establecer más de un par *clave-valor* en una sola llamada.

Ejemplo:

***Usando `set()`***

```
// set()
res.set({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8100',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    });
```

***Usando `header()`***

```
// header()
res.header({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8100',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    });
```

***Usando `setHeader()`***

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```

¿Cuál debemos usar? En principio, el que se adapte a nuestras necesidades. Usar el método de Express permite no ser tan repetitivo en la escritura de nuestro código.

Ahora, cuando establecías el siguiente encabezado:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'
```

No estabas estableciendo la cabecera [`Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin).

Leyendo la documentación de ['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers), vemos que el mismo es usado durante una [petición *preflight*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Preflight_peticion) (petición realizada para comprobar si el protocolo CORS es comprendido entre las partes).

Entre los encabezados que podemos establecer están: ['Content-Type'](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type), ['Accept'](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) y 'X-Requested-With'.

Este último ayuda a evitar cierto tipo de ataques ([CSFR Mitigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)). Puedes leer un poco [aquí](https://markitzeroday.com/x-requested-with/cors/2017/06/29/csrf-mitigation-for-ajax-requests.html) sobre ese tema.

Dado que tenemos opciones para escoger (usar el paquete `cors` o establecer las cabezaras manualmente), debemos hacer una elección.

Una forma en la que puedes tener la configuración de tu Servidor Express es la siguiente: (sin usar el paquete `cors`)

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan'); // <= middleware para logging
const helmet = require('helmet'); // <= middleware para configurar Headers que hacen más segura una aplicación Express
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
// Instanciamos nuestra aplicación Express
const app = express();
//Configuración de nuestra aplicación
app.use(helmet()); // recomiendo siempre usar este middleware y que sea el primero en configurarse en nuestra app
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}); // <= middleware que nos permite parsear body con x-ww-form-urlencoded. Podemos configurarlo con {extended: true} o {extended: false}.
app.use(cookieParser());
//Configuración de las cabezeras para CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100'); //<= sólo permitirá conexiones cruzadas desde esta URI
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
//Configuración del template engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
//Configuración de la ruta para archivos estáticos
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//Configuración de las rutas
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter); //<= esta ruta ha de ir al final de todas las existentes.
app.use('*', notFoundRouter); // <= esto captura las rutas que no existen (Error 404). Debes crear el router para esta ruta.
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App iniciada en puerto 3000');
});
```

Como puedes apreciar en el código, hay algunas cosas que han cambiado de lugar. En particular debo hacer hincapié en el orden de las rutas. La ruta raíz **siempre** debe ir al final de las rutas existentes.

## **CLIENTE**

Del lado cliente no es mucho lo que debes ajustar, pero lo que se debe ajustar es muy importante.

Según lo que subiste a tu repositorio, tienes 1 grave problema.

En el archivo `customer.service.ts` tienes la siguiente línea:

```
console.log('MENSAJE', this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/customers/`));
```

El problema aquí es que `http` que es una instancia de la Clase [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http) de Angular, en realidad devuelve un [`Observable`](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular), por lo tanto para poder obtener los datos de dicha petición, debemos *suscribirnos* al mismo.

Como lo que realizas es tan sencillo (creo que estás aprendiendo a usar Angular) no entraré en detalle sobre cómo implementar tu servicio. Pero si te diré como podrías usar el módulo en este caso.

La forma de realizar la suscripción es la siguiente:

```
this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/customers/`)
    .subscribe(response => { // cuando usas HttpClient se debe usar subscribe()
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Con esto, la respuesta de la solicitud a la ruta `'/customers'` podrá ser mostrada por consola.

Así el problema de CORS y la ausencia de respuesta de `http` deben estar subsanadas.

Puedes leer más sobre Angular en la [guía](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).

Answer (score 1):

Al igual que en otras respuestas que he dado NO recomiendo modificar el servidor para hacer funcionar las aplicaciones sobre todo en ambientes de prueba como lo es un `ionic serve`, este comando ejecuta en tu locahost la aplicación y es logico que no funcione el llamado ya que se hacen de distintos host. La aplicación funcionara sin problemas cuando la ejecutes en un dispositivo. Dentro del archivo `ionic.config.json` puedes agregar la siguiente configuración:

```
"proxies": [
    {
       "path": "/api_test",
       "proxyUrl": "http://url_de_tu_api"
    }
],
```

Y cada llamado que hagas en vez de poner la URL completa solo debes anteponer la palabra que dejaste en la propiedad `path`

```
this.http.get(`/api_test/customers/`)
```

Si no quieres hacer esta configuración te recomiendo instalar la extensión de Chrome para habilitar CORS mientras hagas pruebas.

**EDICION**

Puedo ver que ya tienes esa configuración dentro de tu proyecto pero no la estas ocupando, en tu archivo tienes el `path` como `/api`, haz el llamado asi y funcionara.